# Are there sources for G-d granting non-Jews miracles?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, gentiles, miracle

A friend of mine told me that he once saw in Meam Loez (he thought Yisro) a story about how a group of people on an island had a custom where they walked up a person to a volcano and he jumped in. He then appeared 3 days later and they all celebrated. A Jew once observed this, followed the guy up to the mountain and saw him jump in and die. He then saw that a malach come in the form of this person pretending to be him and still be alive. The point: Since goyim believed in it Hashem had rachmonis and sent an angel to work with their beliefs.

Does anyone know where to find this? Anyone know any sources that discuss G-d and non-Jewish belief? I’ve been curious about if sheidim interact with non-Jews perhaps leading to stories of possession. Maybe G-d allows this for the above reason. Any and all sources which clarify this dynamic are welcome.

Comment: Is Naaman for your reference?

Comment: Naaman is an interesting story, but I suppose I more mean within a context that they take it to be THEIR faith not frum jews acting on their behalf

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in Avodah Zarah that God gives non Jews dreams in which idolatrous deities give them fortuitous instructions or prophecies which come true, but states that it's ultimately a plot to bring their downfall.

Perhaps he is cultivating their faith in the volcano god to get them to jump in all together.